# Making a JFrame button create a Alert Dialog. Java - Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I use NetBeans IDE, as you may know there is a JFrame creator plugin (Its pre-installed) I use it to make JFrames (Because I'm too lazy to do it my self =/). in the event of creating a button within that JFrame it will generate a area for the event code. I was wondering what code i need to type in to generate the Alert Dialog. Heres what is pre-generated upon create a swing/awt component or a JFrame:

```
    public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jDialog2 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog2.getContentPane());
    jDialog2.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog2Layout);
    jDialog2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jDialog2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jDialog2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jDialog2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle(">:D");
    setResizable(false);
    addHierarchyBoundsListener(new java.awt.event.HierarchyBoundsListener() {
        public void ancestorMoved(java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent evt) {
            formAncestorMoved(evt);
        }
        public void ancestorResized(java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent evt) {
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("Press Me :D");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 349, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 180, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //This is the area for the code dialog code
}                                        

private void formAncestorMoved(java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                  

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Did you see the Button1ActionPerformed thing????
that's where the code goes.
I need code that will create a new Alert Dialog (javax.swing.JDialog)
When that is pressed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you might want a `JOptionPane` message dialog...

Try this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<your message here...>", "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

So for your case, this is what your action performed method will look like:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<your message here...>", "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);        
}
```

Note there is no "variable" to store the `JOptionPane` object, it's a *static* method called on the `JOptionPane` class. Each time you want an alert/confirm/input/etc. dialog, you generate one on the fly using the static members of the `JOptionPane` class.

See [the reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) for more info...

Comment: I'm looking to create a javax.swing.JDialog not show an existing one

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to create and show when the button is pressed, or just set some object somewhere? I figure someone who is admittedly "too lazy to do it himself" would look for a chance to re-use existing capability. JOptionPane exists for just this reason...

Comment: Well I mean i have a button and when its clicked I need code to make a new JPANLE. there I want an alert to pop up.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing what the issue is here... you see all that stuff inside `initComponents()`? That's what is involved in creating `JPanel`s and `JDialog`s. If you really want to go that route, then just copy some of that code and modify it to do what you want. I really think the existing `JOptionPane` route is the way you ought to go, but I'm just making a suggestion.

Comment: Nvm I still need help jOptionPane is not a variable XD how do i fix this?

Comment: `showMessageDialog` and most other methods of that class are static, meaning they are invoked on the class, not on an object. why do you need a variable?

Comment: Let me type the error i get with that code:                         Can Not Find Symbol.                                             Symbol: jOptionsPane

Comment: When I typed variable that was different code in a different project

Comment: Type in the code as I have in my solution... `JOptionPane` is the _class_ name, not a variable.

Comment: Want me to upload the jar and you can look through it? And see what I mean?

Comment: Paste the code here if you want help, SO doesn't really like external downloads.

Comment: You don't instantiate it. You statically call the method using the class name. See my edit.

Comment: Ok i saw the edit but thats the button with the code you told me to write where would static go?

Comment: Yes... I'm not really sure what your issue is. I've told you what to do, so outside of that I'm not sure I can be more help without a better understanding of what you ultimately want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i see

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jOptionPane1 = new javax.swing.JOptionPane();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle(">:D");
    setResizable(false);
    addHierarchyBoundsListener(new java.awt.event.HierarchyBoundsListener() {
        public void ancestorMoved(java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent evt) {
            formAncestorMoved(evt);
        }
        public void ancestorResized(java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent evt) {
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("Press Me :D");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 353, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 45, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jOptionPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 46, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 180, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jOptionPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
//jOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<your message here...>", "Alert", jOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);        
}                                        

private void formAncestorMoved(java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                  

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JOptionPane jOptionPane1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: You guys are a huge help. Thanks but I scraped that project sorry thank anyway :)